# Should a private final field be static too?

Tags: java, static

I was wondering, if I have this field in my class : `private final int foo = ...`, should I put it in static `private static final int foo = ...`? Because if it's static, it's common to all the instances of my class, and will never change.

Is there a reason to not put it in static? Or do I have to put it in static?

Comment: `final` does _not_ mean that it's common to all instances of the class.  `static` means that.

Comment: No, if it's `final` it's still restricted to one instance. `static` makes it shared.

Comment: Depends on your requirement. If you are expecting this value to be used in all the objects without any change ie 10 than make it static, if you are going to have different values for each object but which can not be changed after defined once, you could do that by initializing it in constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If every instance of your class should have the *same* immutable value for foo, then you should make foo final and static.  If each instance of your class can have a *different* (but still immutable) value for foo, then the value should just be final.

However, if every instance of your class should have the same immutable value for foo, then it is a really a constant.  By convention, that is typically coded as follows:

```
private static final int FOO = ...
```

Note the caps to denote a constant...

Answer (score 5):

if you initiate its value in the `constructor` then it should not be `static` like

```
private final int foo;

public MyClass(int m){
    foo=m;
}
```

because its value depends on entry value.

---

but if you initiate its value inline like

```
private final int foo = 100;
```

then its preferred to be `static` to have just one instance of it, since the `final` field will be created on each instance of class; but `static` will be created once.

Answer (score 2):

A final member can still be set by the constructor: therefore, if each instance of your class can set foo in the constructor and this value should pertain only to that instance, it should only be final, NOT static.

If however, foo is only set at declaration time, it might mean that this is a common value for all instances and you would win a little memory by declaring it static also. Beware though that if foo was not a primitive but a reference member, final only means that the reference can't change, not the content of the object, therefore a final and non static member that is a reference should not automatically be static. You could want one immutable reference per instance of your class, with different object state.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between the two non-access modifiers.

- `final` means your variable can be assigned a value once.
- `static` sets its scope to pertain to the class (rather than an instance or a local context).

There is no reason why they should go together unless by design.

A `static final` variable is *de facto* a **constant**.

For instance, fields declared in `interface`s are implicitly `public`, `static` and `final`.

Amongst the usage examples for `final`, non `static` fields you can find:

- fields declared outside an anonymous class and being referenced inside it
- local fields (declared in a method's body) being referenced inside a local class (declared in the same method's body)
- etc...

Answer (score 1):

It is a constant and you will not want to have one copy of the variable for each instance of the class,so make it static. Also, if you want to use them from a static method, make it static.

Static variables are those variables which are common for all the instances of a class.If one instance changes it, then value of static variable would be updated for all other instances.

If you do not want this behavior, keep it non-static.